# How to capture warnings in dbatools commands?

Tags: powershell, dbatools

**Context:**

I need to be able to catch warnings that are preventing some backups from being restored when using the Restore-DbaDatabase cmdlet.

I found some posts mentioning that the **-Silent** parameter for the **Restore-DbaDatabase** would treat those warnings as errors so I could catch them, but this parameter no longer exists.

I'm using the **-EnableException** parameter with no luck. Warnings are shown on screen, but I'm unable to catch them in my scripts since no Exception is thrown, as show in the following image:

[image: Restore-DbaDatabase not treating warnings as errors when -EnableException is specified]

**Question:**

What is the right approach to catch/capture all the warnings for a dbatools command?

Comment: You need to redirect the **Warning Stream** to stdout. `3>&1`. See [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: You can also use `$WarningPreference = 'Stop'` at the beginning of your script, then the Warnings will be treated as Exceptions.

Comment: You should be able to use the `-WarningVariable` common parameter to capture emitted warnings without stream redirection. I don't know that dbatools supports it.

Answer (score 0):

A little rough, however, here is what I do:

```
$response = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $sql_host -Database $sql_db -Query $sql_insert_new_response 3>&1
if ($response -match "Failed during execution") {
  Write-Log -Message "Error: $($response.Message). Skipping."
  continue
}
```